# Is there a terminal command that navigates to the deepest sub-directory in a directory?

Tags: scripting, terminal

What I mean is that, suppose we have the following directory

Dropbox (folder)

---> Bob (folder)

-------> 2017 (folder)

------------> images (folder)

----------------> image.png (file)

I could do 
`cd Dropbox`, but then I have to manually navigate all the way to the deepest directory `images`.

Is there a command like
`cd Dropbox:deepest directory` that will take me to `Dropbox/Bob/2017/images`?

**If there is a tie on any level, then stop at that level**

Comment: What should happen if there is a tie on depth e.g. `Bob/2017/images` and `Bob/2017/music` ?

Comment: In the case that there are > 1 folders, stop there then

Comment: Use a shell with fancy completion (like `zsh`). Then you only type very few keys.

Comment: type cd then keep pressing tabs until it no longer expands.

Comment: @LieRyan this is precisely what I wanted to avoid

Comment: @KSplitX: is there any specific reason why you think that is not preferable? Personally, I think as long as you are doing this in interactive terminal, the tab completion is much easier and simpler than most of the suggestions below. If your shell's autocomplete are configured correctly, it should only autocomplete to directories when you start the command with cd, and if there's only one choices, it'd just be a matter of holding down tab, no?

Comment: I agree with you, but the truth is that sometimes I don't know how many subdirectories I will have, and so in that case it is easier to use the answers and not the tab key

Comment: In regards to the tie-on-depth question earlier, should the processing stop if there's a tie, even if one of those branches has more subdirectories?

Comment: I want it to stop, because sometimes I want to go to the smaller subdirectory folder, so in this case it is safer to just stop whenever we reach a tie

Comment: I don't understand your _If there is a tie on any level, then stop at that level_ edit. What do you mean? The question is if there's a `a/b/c/d` and `w/x/y/z` which should be selected?

Comment: I think I get it now. It should not change directory in that case and in `a/b/c/d` vs `a/b/x/y` it should change to `a/b` but if it's `a/b/c/d` vs `a/b/x/y/z` it should change to `a/b/x/y/z`. Is that right?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas My understanding is this (I feel OP meaning the same): 1) There is directory tree `A/B/C/D`, `deep_cd.sh` does next - go to the deepest directory, in this case it is `D`. 2) Take another directory tree: `A/B/C/D` `A/B/X/Y`. `deep_cd.sh` does next - go to the nearest fork and wait, when user pick next branch - either `C/D` or `X/Y`. Fork is in the `B` directory - go there and stop. Farther user moving by standard way. `deep_cd.sh` is needed only for skipping routine actions: `A` tab `B` tab `C` tab `D` tab.

Comment: @K Split X By the way, do you check my solution (two functions - select any)? They do what you want. Everything as you ordered :) Or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
bydepth() REPLY=${REPLY//[^\/]}
cd Dropbox/**/*(D/O+bydepth[1])
```

We define a `bydepth` sorting function that returns the file with the characters other than `/` removed (so the order after that transformation is on depth) and use recursive globbing (`**/` being any level of subdirectories) with glob qualifiers:

- `D` to also consider hidden dirs
- `/` for only dirs
- `O+bydepth`: reverse sort by depth
- `[1]` get the first one only (after sorting).

With `bash` and GNU tools, the equivalent would be something like:

```
IFS= read -rd '' deepest < <(find Dropbox/ -type d -print0 |
  awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' -F / '
    NF > max {max = NF; deepest = $0}
    END {if (max) print deepest}') && cd -- "$deepest"
```

(in case of ties, the chosen one will not necessarily be the same as in the `zsh` approach).

With your new extra requirement, it becomes more complicated. Basically, if I understand correctly, in case of  ties, it should change to the directory that is the deepest common parent of all those directories at the maximum depth. With `zsh`:

```
cd_deepest() {
  setopt localoptions rematchpcre
  local REPLY dirs result dir match
  dirs=(${1:-.}/**/*(ND/nOne:'
   REPLY=${#REPLY//[^\/]}-$REPLY':))
  (($#dirs)) || return
  result=$dirs[1]
  for dir ($dirs[2,-1]) {
    [[ $result//$dir =~ '^([^-]*-.*)/.*//\1/' ]] || break
    result=$match[1]
  }
  cd -- ${result#*-} && print -rD -- $PWD
}
```

Example:

```
$ tree Dropbox
Dropbox
├── a
│   └── b
│       ├── 1
│       │   └── x
│       └── 2
│           └── x
└── c
    └── d
        └── e

9 directories, 0 files
$ cd_deepest Dropbox
~/Dropbox/a/b
```

(`Dropbox/a/b/1/x` and `Dropbox/a/b/2/x` are the deepest ones, and we change to their deepest common parent (`Dropbox/a/b`)).

Comment: If we are in the Dropbox directory, then we are in our common directory already. And script doesn't need go furhter. Because Dropbox directory contain fork: `a` path and `c` path and now user must choose next path by manually. Look at my solution - I implement it by recursion, just now.

Comment: Using `tree` command is very convenient. Didn't know about it, was using `ls` for checking directory tree :).

Comment: @MiniMax, I'm not sure I understand what you mean `Dropbox/a/b` is the deepest directory that is an ancestor of both the deepest directories. Your `rcd` would stop at the first level that contains more that one non-hidden directory (or symlink to directory). In any case, we'd need the OP to clarify what he wants

Comment: "stop at the first level that contains more that one non-hidden directory" - exactly, how I understand question. Stop, if the directory have more than one directory inside. Let user resolve ambiguity and choose next path. Change to the next directory, if it is single one. It is that OP was asked. Script must repeat `Tab` presses instead of the user, when choice is obvious (because, no choice - only one directory). It will help, If we have many single directories nested inside each other. Like `Dropbox/a/b/c/d/e` - we are needing `e` dir. We run `rcd Dropbox` and it moves us to `e` dir.

Comment: @MiniMax, yes I suppose it's another possible interpretation of what the OP's asking for. That means that if there's a `a`, `b`, and `c/d/e/f/g/h` directory, it doesn't go to the deepest directory however. The cases where such a function would be useful would be quite rare AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do echo -n $(echo "$line" | grep -o '/' | wc -l); echo " $line"; done | sort | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f2-`

Tested on macOS (bash) and Arch Linux (zsh and bash).

- `find . -type d` is used to find all directories in the current path.
- `-print0` in combination with `read` is used to handle the output from find also for directories that may contain spaces.
- `grep -o` is used to pick out the slashes from the paths.
- `wc -l` is used to count the number of slashes.
- `sort` and `tail` are used to pick out the path that contains the most slashes.
- `cut` is used to discard the slash number and only show the path to the deepest directory.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bash-centric version; it relies on the following bash features:

- [globstar shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash//manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) to enable directory and subdirectory expansion with `**/`
- [read that supports arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash//manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) to count directory depths

```bash
cdd() {
  local _cdd_unset_globstar=0
  shopt -q globstar || _cdd_unset_globstar=1
  shopt -s globstar
  local _cdd_deepest=$1
  local _cdd_level=1
  local _cdd_array=()
  for d in "${1}/"**/
  do
    IFS=/ read -r -d '' -a _cdd_array <<< "$d" || true
    if [ "${#_cdd_array[*]}" -gt "$_cdd_level" ]
    then
      _cdd_deepest=$d
      _cdd_level=${#_cdd_array[*]}
    fi
  done
  cd -- "$_cdd_deepest" && true
  local _cdd_ret="$?"
  [ "$_cdd_unset_globstar" -eq 1 ] && shopt -u globstar
  return "$_cdd_ret"
}
```

The function does the following things:

1. checks to see if the globstar shell option is already set; if not, then we save a flag to reset the option at the end.
2. initialize the currently-deepest known directory and it's level (`$1` and `1`, respectively).
3. Expand every subdirectory under the given parameter and loop over them.
4. For each subdirectory, read it into an array, delimited by `/`; count the number of elements in the array and compare it to the currently-known deepest directory level. If it's deeper, reset those variables.
5. Once we have the deepest subdirectory, `cd` to it.
6. If we should reset the globstar shell option, do so.

If it seems cleaner to you to use a subshell to set the shell options, then you could approach it with two functions: a wrapper and a subshell-invoking function that does the above:

```
cdd_helper() (
  shopt -s globstar
  _cdd_deepest=$1
  _cdd_level=1
  for d in "${1}/"**/
  do
    IFS=/ read -r -d '' -a _cdd_array <<< "$d" || true
    if [ "${#_cdd_array[*]}" -gt "$_cdd_level" ]
    then
      _cdd_deepest=$d
      _cdd_level=${#_cdd_array[*]}
    fi
  done
  printf "%s" "$_cdd_deepest"
)

cdd() {
  cd -- "$(cdd_helper "$1")"
}
```

Comment: Note that this will expand only non-hidden directories by default; if you'd like to include hidden directories (`.dirname`), then use `shopt -s dotglob`.

Comment: Which purpose the `cd -- "$_cdd_deepest" && true` line in the `cdd` function? Why the `&& true` added? If `cd` will run successfully, exit status will be 0, if unsuccessfully, then  `&& true` will not executed anyway.

Comment: @MiniMax that cancels the effect of a potential `set -e` while still preserving the exit status of cd

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Don't understand... From `man bash`: *"`command1 && command2` - command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an  exit  status of zero."* Therefore, if `cd` return **0**, then `true` executed and also return **0**. If `cd` return **1**, then `true` is not executed and whole expression return **1** as well. `&& true` changes nothing (in my opinion, may be I miss something). When `|| true` is added, I am understanding purpose - `cd` fails, but `|| true` prevent script from termination (if `set -e` enabled), changing exit status from **1** to **0**.

Comment: I had to look it up, too. Under `set -e`, the shell would exit if `cd` failed, except: `The shell does  not exit  if  the  command  that  fails is ... part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following
the  final && or ||, ...` so the `true` is never executed, but is there soley to enable this behavior under `set -e`

Comment: @MiniMax, one might argue (and I'd probably agree) that it's uncalled for here. That cdd would typically be called in interactive shells where you'd typically _not_ use `set -e`. Sensible persons would not use `set -e` in scripts that use functions if at all. I added `||true` to `read` after adding the missing `-d ''` as then `read` would always fail though it should not be considered a failure. I added it to `cd` for consistency, though depending on the version of `bash`, it may not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using `find` and `sort` to determine the deepest directories:

```
$ pwd
/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests
$ find $PWD -type d -printf '%d:%p\0' |sort -z -t: -r |awk -F: -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\n' 'NR<=3'   #Print the top 3 deepest dirs
5:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/tmp/tmp2/tmp3/tmp4/tmp 5  #mind the space in last dir name
5:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin
4:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/tmp/tmp2/tmp3/tmp4
```

With `-printf` option of `find` you can select what to print:
`%d`: The directory depth from the cwd
`%p` : The name of the result = directory name
`\0` : nul delimiter

You can step into the first deepest directory like:

```
$ cd "$(find $PWD -type d -printf '%d:%p\0' |sort -z -t: -r |awk -F: -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\n' 'NR==1{print $2}')"
$ pwd
/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/tmp/tmp2/tmp3/tmp4/tmp 5
```

To avoid remembering all these, you can stick a function in your alias file to be loaded with your bash profile:

```
$ deepest () { cd "$(find $PWD -type d -printf '%d:%p\0' |sort -z -t: -r |awk -F: -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\n' 'NR==1{print $2}')"; }

$ pwd
/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests
$ deepest
$ pwd
/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/tmp/tmp2/tmp3/tmp4/tmp 5
```

Answer (score 1):

#### First way - recursion, best in my opinion.

**Usage:** load function `rcd` in to the bash `source recur_cd.sh`, then test it: `rcd some_dir`.

```
rcd () {
    if [ ! -d "$*" ]; then
        return 121 
    else
        rcd "${*}"*/
    fi  

    if (($? == 121)); then 
        cd "$*" 
    fi
}
```

#### Second way - command find (two variants here).

**Usage:** Firstly, load two inner functions (`dcd1` and `dcd2`) in to the `bash`, by this command: `source deep_cd.sh`. Functions do the same, but implemented differently.

Then, test it:

```
dcd1 dir   # first variant
pwd
cd -       # return back for further testing`<br>
dcd2 dir   # second variant
pwd
           # and so on.
```

**deep_cd.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# first variant, support filenames with spaces, work by awk mainly 
dcd1 () {
    cd "$(find "$1" -type d -printf "%d %p\n" | sort | awk '{
        a[$1]++; 
        tmp_num=$1;
        sub("^[0-9]* ", "", $0);
        path = $0;
        if (a[tmp_num] == 2) { sub("[^/]*$", ""); path = $0; exit; }
    }
    END { print path; }')"
}

# second variant, support filenames with spaces - more programs 
# used (cut, uniq, tail), awk only prints the path, doesn't search it
dcd2 () {
    str=$(find "$1" -type d -printf "%d %p\n" | sort)
    num=$(cut -d " " -f 1 <<< "$str" | uniq -u | tail -n 1)
    path=$(awk -v n=$num 'NR == n+1 { $1=""; print $0; }' <<< "$str")
    cd "${path# }"
}
```

#### Third way - readline macros usage.

`bind '"\e\C-i":"\C-i\C-i\C-i\C-i"'` That's all :)

**Explanation:**

- `bind` - read `help bind`. It is readline function for key binding.
- `\e\C-i` - <kbd>Ctlr</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> - new bond combination, when it will be pressed, it will make autocomplete series, before two or more directories emerge.
- `\C-i` is the same as <kbd>Tab</kbd>, meaning 'complete'. You need as many `\C-i` as you suppose directory depth. If supposed 10 levels, so you need 10 `\C-i` blocks. Though, may be more convenient will be choose middle number of blocks, like 3 or 4 and just press `Alt + Ctrl + i` combination twice, where it is needed. It will prevent output repeating (see comments in the **"Testing"** section)

If you want make this behavior permanent, then add this line to the `.bashrc`

**Testing**

```
cd o                        # then Alt + Ctrl + i
cd one/two/three/four/      # directory has changed to deepest

cd A                        # then Alt + Ctrl + i
cd A/B/C/                   # directory has changed to deepest
D/ E/                       # and two inner directories appear
~/deepest_dir$ cd A/B/C/    # one drawback here - if deepest 
D/ E/                       # directory is reached, then completion
~/deepest_dir$ cd A/B/C/    # works idle and print duplicating
                            # output, so may be worth shrinks 'C-i'
                            # blocks amount in the binding string
```

Comment: The readline macro thing may work in `bash`, but not in other shells.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, but as well as other solutions with coding, if they use `bash` features. Only POSIX compatible code will give full confidence. Right? By the way, is it only `bash` uses readline library? Or exist another  shells, which use it too?

Comment: I only pointed it out as you did not mention it. I'm not aware of another shell that uses readline, but you could _possibly_ try to wrap it (the shell invocation) in `rlwrap` (I haven't tried this and I'm definitely not sure that it works).