# Achieving the effect of a recursive rmdir

Tags: shell, directory, rm

As far as I can see, `rmdir` might well have had the option
`-r`, to remove the argument's reference only if it contained only directories and no
file anywhere in the tree.  What's the simplest way of doing
that?

Answer (score 4):

GNU `find`, and current BSDs’ `find` (including macOS), have a `-delete` action which can be used for this:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

will find any empty directories and delete them. The `-delete` action activates depth-first processing, so that directories which only contain other directories, and no files in any sub-directory, will be deleted.

Comment: FreeBSD `find`, too.   OpenBSD `find` has `-empty`but not `-delete`.  I don't know about MacOS off the top of my head.

Comment: @JdeBP [OpenBSD's `find` does have a `-delete`](https://man.openbsd.org/find#-delete), and so does NetBSD's and macOS' `find` too.

Comment: That's a recent import from FreeBSD.  It didn't have it in the version that I brought up to check whether it had it.  (-:

Answer (score 0):

You could use the zsh shell to recursively expand the argument into the list of (sub)directories, reverse-sorted by depth; then `rmdir` can process the list in order. It will succeed only when each directory is empty and will provide warnings (and *not* remove the directory) when it is not empty. This will have the result of deleting empty directory trees and emitting warnings when directories are not empty.

I've borrowed the `bydepth` function from [Stéphane's answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370265/117549).

```
bydepth() REPLY=${REPLY//[^\/]}
rmdir **/(/O+bydepth)
```

The `bydepth` function (re)sets the REPLY variable by stripping out all of the non-forward-slash characters.  That REPLY string is then used by the sorting function in the glob qualifier `O+` to order them longest-first.  The other glob qualifier is `/`, which selects only directories. The initial `**/` wildcard tells zsh to recursively expand from the current directory.

Sample runs:

```
$ : no files exist
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d
$ find .
.
./a
./a/b
./a/b/c
./a/b/c/d
$ rmdir **/(/O+bydepth)
$ find .
.
$ 
$ : a file exists
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d
$ touch a/b/c/somefile
$ find .
.
./a
./a/b
./a/b/c
./a/b/c/d
./a/b/c/somefile
$ rmdir **/(/O+bydepth)
rmdir: failed to remove ‘a/b/c/’: Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove ‘a/b/’: Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove ‘a/’: Directory not empty
$ find .
.
./a
./a/b
./a/b/c
./a/b/c/somefile
```